# PhotoMOS simulation circuit

Tags: solid-state-relay, circuitlab

I want to simulate the following [PhotoMos](http://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Panasonic-Industrial-Devices/AQY412S/?qs=wKtUvITRianLDfJVWHqruA%3D%3D) in CircuitLab for switching circuit but i didn't find the model for any photomos in CircuitLab. I was preparing a simulation for a switching MOSFET circuit and i need a PhotoMos model in my simulation, but i didn't find a PHOTOMOS model in CircuitLab.

How to insert a photoMos in CircuitLab simulation ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is : How to insert a photoMos in CircuitLab simulation ?

Comment: Your photomos is in fact a new name for a photovoltaic stack tied to a BOSFET .This solid state relay is probably as slow as a wet week because the photovoltaic stack makes microamps to charge nanofarad gate source capacitances for low on resistance.This is featured on www.badbeetles.com.